# Printing complete coo_matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I tried to instantiate a `coo_matrix` using another matrix. When I tried to print the `coo_matrix`, the output is:

```
(1, 9)  1.0
(1, 10) 1.0
(1, 11) 1.0
(1, 25) 1.0
(1, 47) 1.0
(2, 1)  1.0
(2, 7)  1.0
(2, 11) 3.0
(2, 12) 1.0
(2, 13) 1.0
(2, 15) 2.0
(2, 19) 1.0
(2, 42) 1.0
(3, 0)  1.0
(4, 20) 1.0
(4, 22) 1.0
(4, 24) 1.0
:   :
(45, 0) 1.0
(45, 7) 1.0
(45, 14)    2.0
(45, 20)    1.0
(45, 26)    1.0
(45, 38)    1.0
(45, 40)    1.0
(46, 11)    1.0
(46, 19)    1.0
(46, 36)    1.0
(46, 41)    1.0
(46, 47)    1.0
```

How do I print the complete `coo_matrix`? I tried using `set_printoptions(threshold = 'nan')` but it doesn't work on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "complete" in this context?

Comment: Do you want to see all the nonzero values, or the whole matrix including the 0s?  Normally a sparse matrix is too large to show in full, that's why it has 2 different abbreviated displays (`repr(a)` and `str(a)`).  To see the 0s you have to make it dense again.

Comment: I want to see the only nonzero values.

Comment: `print(matrix.data)` will print the values of the nonzero elements as a 1D array. Is that what you want?

Comment: @BhuvanReddy: You want to see only the nonzero values. You're seeing only the nonzero values. What's the problem?

Comment: @ali_m I need the row and column as well. anyways I got it. Thanks

Comment: @user2357112: The list doesn't contain the entire list. It shows only part of the matrix when I print it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your sparse matrix to a dense matrix using `.todense()` method:

```
print(my_coo_matrix.todense())
```

**Edit:** Your question sounded like you want to print the zero valued elements too, however if you only want to print nonzero elements, you can iterate the matrix manually:

```
for row, col, value in zip(my_coo_matrix.row, my_coo_matrix.col, my_coo_matrix.data):
    print "({0}, {1}) {2}".format(row, col, value)
```

Comment: That helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I find it helpful to visually represent it using spy().

```
spy(coo_matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

(for VERY LARGE coo_matrix) export to `csv`, then saving it as `xlsx` may help.

Example:

```
import numpy
numpy.savetxt('coo_matrix.csv', coo_matrix.todense(), delimiter = ',')
```